# Show div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a show and hide for div in JavaScript but the code is displayed and hidden very quickly. I don't know if my code is wrong.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
   function sendpost(){
   var u = $('#myform').serialize();
 $.post('post.php',u,function(outpot){
      $('#alert').html(outpot).show().fadeOut(4000);
      $('#myform').fadeOut(1000).delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
   });
   }
   </script>
```

HTML

```
 <div class="formone">
        <div id="alert"></div>

<form id="myform">
        Past your link here and Click "Short Now"
       <input type='text' id='mytext'  name='link' size='70' />
       <input type='submit' onclick="sendpost();" value="Short Now" />
</form>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using css3 transition also this is better for perfomance ! ;-)

```js
var dom = {
  $input: $('.input'),
  $alertContainer: $('.alert')
};

dom.$input.on('click', function() {
  /* $.post('post.php',u,function(outpot){
   * ...
   * your magic
   */
  dom.$alertContainer.addClass('show');
});
```

```css
.alert {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background: #99cc00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formone">
  <div class="alert">Lorem ipsum tu lis ma nore, Lorem ipsum a lot of lorem isum</div>
  <form id="myform">
    Past your link here and Click "Short Now"
    <input type='text' id='mytext' name='link' size='70' />
    <input type='submit' class="input" value="Short Now" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess it's good but I want to show the message for 4 seconds and hide it automatic

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
   // this will prevent the form from being sent - reloading the page
   e.preventDefault();
   var u = $(this).serialize();
   $.post('post.php',u,function(outpot){
       $('#alert').html(outpot).show().fadeOut(4000);
       $('#myform').fadeOut(1000).delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type='submit' value="Short Now" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks you for ur help 
I put a message in post.php when it's empty to show an Error message and it's showen but in one second and it's gone qweqly
i tried your code but it's still the same problem

Comment: @Abdedaim Maybe adding a delay before fading out the alert would be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Abdedaim Is there any chance you could give us a full HTML page's code that reproduces the problem? You can paste it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), so we can look at it and see what's wrong.

Comment: Thx u very much I find the problem was only in input button I change it to  <button><a></a></button>  and it's worked :D